# ui-datepicker with ui-grid issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid, angular-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to update a editableCellTemplate in a ui-grid to include ui-datepicker so I'll allow user to have the possibility to select date using firefox or IE, but with no success.
Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Duf22sBYidRynO8Igewx?p=preview) with what I'm trying to do, using `editableCellTemplate: '<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px; position:absolute;"><div uib-datepicker  class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-focus="open()" style="background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 0; padding: 8px;" >'`

Comment: take a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4mNr86cN6wFOLYQ02QND?p=preview

Comment: @Yaser thank you soo much for this update, however do you know how to handle the calendar option in this case? I mean if I want to change the min and max date, do you have any idea? `$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example with a ui-datepicker directive with all details and options.
you can find details in this [github link](https://github.com/Joiler/ui-grid-edit-datepicker) and this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lMrVPfLuHfSgWmtlxG9G?p=preview) example where ui-datepicker directive looks like below:

```
var app = angular.module('ui.grid.edit');

app.directive('uiGridEditDatepicker', ['$timeout', '$document', 'uiGridConstants', 'uiGridEditConstants', function($timeout, $document, uiGridConstants, uiGridEditConstants) {
return {
    template: function(element, attrs) {    
        var html = '<div class="datepicker-wrapper" ><input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup datepicker-options="datepickerOptions" datepicker-append-to-body="true" is-open="isOpen" ng-model="datePickerValue" ng-change="changeDate($event)" popup-placement="auto top"/></div>';
        return html;
    },
    require: ['?^uiGrid', '?^uiGridRenderContainer'],
    scope: true,
    compile: function() {
        return {
            pre: function($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
                if ($attrs.datepickerOptions){
                    if ($scope.col.grid.appScope[$attrs.datepickerOptions]){
                        $scope.datepickerOptions = $scope.col.grid.appScope[$attrs.datepickerOptions];
                    }
                }
            },
            post: function($scope, $elm, $attrs, controllers) {
                var setCorrectPosition = function() {
                    var gridElement = $('.ui-grid-viewport');
                    var gridPosition = {
                        width: gridElement.outerWidth(),
                        height: gridElement.outerHeight(),
                        offset: gridElement.offset()
                    };

                    var cellElement = $($elm);
                    var cellPosition = {
                        width: cellElement.outerWidth(),
                        height: cellElement.outerHeight(),
                        offset: cellElement.offset()
                    };

                    var datepickerElement = $('body > .dropdown-menu, body > div > .dropdown-menu');
                    var datepickerPosition = {
                        width: datepickerElement.outerWidth(),
                        height: datepickerElement.outerHeight()
                    };

                    var setCorrectTopPositionInGrid = function() {
                        var topPosition;
                        var freePixelsOnBottom = gridPosition.height - (cellPosition.offset.top - gridPosition.offset.top) - cellPosition.height;
                        var freePixelsOnTop = gridPosition.height - freePixelsOnBottom - cellPosition.height;
                        var requiredPixels = (datepickerPosition.height - cellPosition.height) / 2;
                        if (freePixelsOnBottom >= requiredPixels && freePixelsOnTop >= requiredPixels) {
                            topPosition = cellPosition.offset.top - requiredPixels + 10;
                        } else if (freePixelsOnBottom >= requiredPixels && freePixelsOnTop < requiredPixels) {
                            topPosition = cellPosition.offset.top - freePixelsOnTop + 10;
                        } else {
                            topPosition = gridPosition.height - datepickerPosition.height + gridPosition.offset.top - 20;
                        }
                        return topPosition;
                    };

                    var setCorrectTopPositionInWindow = function() {
                        var topPosition;
                        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight - 10;

                        var freePixelsOnBottom = windowHeight - cellPosition.offset.top;
                        var freePixelsOnTop = windowHeight - freePixelsOnBottom - cellPosition.height;
                        var requiredPixels = (datepickerPosition.height - cellPosition.height) / 2;
                        if (freePixelsOnBottom >= requiredPixels && freePixelsOnTop >= requiredPixels) {
                            topPosition = cellPosition.offset.top - requiredPixels;
                        } else if (freePixelsOnBottom >= requiredPixels && freePixelsOnTop < requiredPixels) {
                            topPosition = cellPosition.offset.top - freePixelsOnTop;
                        } else {
                            topPosition = windowHeight - datepickerPosition.height - 10;
                        }
                        return topPosition;
                    };


                    var newOffsetValues = {};

                    var isFreeOnRight = (gridPosition.width - (cellPosition.offset.left - gridPosition.offset.left) - cellPosition.width) > datepickerPosition.width;
                    if (isFreeOnRight) {
                        newOffsetValues.left = cellPosition.offset.left + cellPosition.width;
                    } else {
                        newOffsetValues.left = cellPosition.offset.left - datepickerPosition.width;
                    }

                    if (datepickerPosition.height < gridPosition.height) {
                        newOffsetValues.top = setCorrectTopPositionInGrid();
                    } else {
                        newOffsetValues.top = setCorrectTopPositionInWindow();
                    }

                    datepickerElement.offset(newOffsetValues);
                    datepickerElement.css("visibility", "visible");
                };

                $timeout(function() {
                    setCorrectPosition();
                }, 0);



                $scope.datePickerValue = new Date($scope.row.entity[$scope.col.field]);
                $scope.isOpen = true;
                var uiGridCtrl = controllers[0];
                var renderContainerCtrl = controllers[1];

                var onWindowClick = function (evt) {
                    var classNamed = angular.element(evt.target).attr('class');
                    if (classNamed) {
                        var inDatepicker = (classNamed.indexOf('datepicker-calendar') > -1);
                        if (!inDatepicker && evt.target.nodeName !== "INPUT") {
                            $scope.stopEdit(evt);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.stopEdit(evt);
                    }
                };

                var onCellClick = function (evt) {
                    angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.ui-grid-cell-contents')).off('click', onCellClick);
                    $scope.stopEdit(evt);
                };

                $scope.changeDate = function (evt) {
                    $scope.row.entity[$scope.col.field] = $scope.datePickerValue;
                    $scope.stopEdit(evt);
                };

                $scope.$on(uiGridEditConstants.events.BEGIN_CELL_EDIT, function () {
                    if (uiGridCtrl.grid.api.cellNav) {
                        uiGridCtrl.grid.api.cellNav.on.navigate($scope, function (newRowCol, oldRowCol) {
                            $scope.stopEdit();
                        });
                    } else {
                        angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.ui-grid-cell-contents')).on('click', onCellClick);
                    }
                    angular.element(window).on('click', onWindowClick);
                });

                $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    angular.element(window).off('click', onWindowClick);
                    $('body > .dropdown-menu, body > div > .dropdown-menu').remove();
                });

                $scope.stopEdit = function(evt) {
                    $scope.$emit(uiGridEditConstants.events.END_CELL_EDIT);
                };

                $elm.on('keydown', function(evt) {
                    switch (evt.keyCode) {
                        case uiGridConstants.keymap.ESC:
                            evt.stopPropagation();
                            $scope.$emit(uiGridEditConstants.events.CANCEL_CELL_EDIT);
                            break;
                    }
                    if (uiGridCtrl && uiGridCtrl.grid.api.cellNav) {
                        evt.uiGridTargetRenderContainerId = renderContainerCtrl.containerId;
                        if (uiGridCtrl.cellNav.handleKeyDown(evt) !== null) {
                            $scope.stopEdit(evt);
                        }
                    } else {
                        switch (evt.keyCode) {
                            case uiGridConstants.keymap.ENTER:
                            case uiGridConstants.keymap.TAB:
                                evt.stopPropagation();
                                evt.preventDefault();
                                $scope.stopEdit(evt);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                });
            }
        };
    }
};
}]);
```